# Prove that if $n^2$ is divided by 3, then also $n$ can also be divided by 3.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> $n\in \Bbb N$
>
> Prove that if $n^2$ is divided by 3, then also n can also be divided by 3.

I started solving this by induction, but I'm not sure that I'm going in the right direction, any suggestions?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with calculus or division algebras.

Comment: If a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$, then either $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. You have that $p$ divides the product $n \cdot n = n^2$. So, what can you say?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009637/prove-that-if-3-mid-n2-then-3-mid-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Decomposing into a product of primes, suppose $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_n^{k_n}$ where $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$.  What happens to the prime decomposition when $n$ is squared?  What if $p|n^2$ for some prime $p$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $p|ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b$ if $p$ is a prime

Comment: This is not true. 4|10*2 but 4 does not divide 10 and 4 does not divide 2

Comment: @mathtastic So what you're saying is... $4$ is prime.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention p should be a prime when I firstly posted the answer

Comment: Edward Jiang - No. 4 is obviously not prime. However, that condition was an edit added after I made my comment. The statement is now true. The original statement was: $p|ab$ implies $p|a$ or $p|b$

Answer (score 4):

For every $n\in\mathbb Z$ you have three possible cases. Either $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$ (for some $k\in\mathbb Z$).

Let us consider each of these cases separately:

- If $n=3k$, then $n^2=(3k)^2=3(3k^2)$, which means $3\mid n^2$.
- If $n=3k+1$, then $n^2=(3k+1)^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1$. This implies $3\nmid n^2$.
- If $n=3k+2$, then $n^2=(3k+2)^2=9k^2+12k+4=3(3k^2+4k+1)+1$. So we have again $3\nmid n^2$.

So we see that if $3\nmid n$ (i.e., in the last two cases), then $3\nmid n^2$. This is the same as saying that $3\mid n^2$ implies $3\mid n$.

Notice that we have in fact proved also that if $3\nmid n$, then the remainder of $n^2$ modulo $3$ is $1$.

Once you learn a bit about [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation), you will be able to write down arguments like this in more elegant and more economical way.
This is the way it was done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/992198).

Maybe it is also worth to mention that instead of $n=3k+2$ we can use $n=3k-1$. This can sometimes simplify the calculations slightly. (In this case we get $n^2=(3k-1)^2=9k^2-6k+1=3(3k^2-2k)+1$.)

Comment: Thank you.

The only problem I now have is that it seems we can do the same with proving 4 | p^2 => 4 | p, because:

If p = 4k then p^2 = (4k)^2 = 4(4k^2) => 4|p^2
If p = 4k + 1 then 4 does not divide p^2
If p = 4k + 2 then 4 does not divide p^2

So we see that if 4 does not divide p (i.e., in the last two cases), then 4 does not divide p^2. This is the same as saying that 4 does not divide p^2 implies 4 divides p.

(But this is not true for p = 2).

Comment: If $n=4k+2$ then $n^2=(4k+2)^2=16k^2+16k+4=4(4k^2+4k+1)$ and $4\mid n^2$. So the same argument does not work with $4$ instead of $3$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

if $n\equiv 0,1,2 \mod 3$ then $n^2\equiv 0,1 \mod 3$ therefore $n^2\equiv 0\mod 3$ then $n \equiv 0 \mod 3$

Answer (score 1):

Everything comes from Bézout's lemma. Suppose that $3$ does not divide $n$, then $GCD(3, n) = 1$ and there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $3a + nb = 1$. Now if you multiply both sides by n you get $3an + n^2b = n$. $3$ divides the left hand side, so it divides $n$ too, which gives the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contrapositive:
("If $3 \not \mid n$,  then $ 3 \not \mid n^2 $" is logically equivalent to "If $3\mid n^2$,  then $ 3\mid n $")

Since we have $3 \not \mid n$, then there are remainders $r=1,2$ So, we have that $n=3k_1+1$ or $n=3k_2+2$ for some $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, if $n=3k_1+1$ we have that $n^2=9k_1^2+6k_1+1$. Note $n^2=3(3k_1^2+2k_1)+1$, where $3k_1^2+2k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\mathbb{N}$ closed under multiplication and addition. So, since we have remainder $r=1$ we see that $3 \not\mid n^2$.

Then, if $n=3k_2+2$ we have that $n^2=9k_2^2+12k_2+4$. Note $n^2=3(3k_2^2+4k_2+1)+1$, where $3k_2^2+4k_2+1\in \mathbb{N}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ closed under multiplication and addition. So, since we have remainder $r=1$ we see that $3 \not\mid n^2$

Thus, we have that $3 \not\mid n^2$, which shows the contrapositive to be true.

Q.E.D.

Comment: First line ("If $3\mid n$,  then $ 3\mid n^2 $") is mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is an integer, so by Euclid's algorithm, $n=3a+b$ where $a$ is an integer, and $b$ is either 0,1 or 2, then $n^2=9a^2+6ab+b^2$, and therefore $3|n^2\Rightarrow 3|b^2$. And now we got Dr. Sonhard Graubner proof as $3|b^2\Rightarrow b^2\neq 1,4\Rightarrow b\neq 1,2 \Rightarrow b=0\Rightarrow n=3a\Rightarrow 3|n$

Answer (score 0):

As fan wrote, if $p$ is prime and divides $ab$ then $p$ divides either $a$ or $b$ (or both). Here is a proof of that theorem.

Since the only divisors of a prime number are $1$ and itself, either $GCD(p,a)=1$ or $GCD(p,a)=p$. (GCD means **G**reatest **C**ommon **D**ivisor.) The second means that $p$ divides $a$ and we're done.

If $GCD(p,a)=1$ then by Bezout's theorem we can find integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$px+ay=1$$
Multiply this by $b$ and we get
$$pbx+(ab)y=b$$

$p$ obviously divides the first term and by hypothesis it divides the second, so $p$ must also divide the third term, $b$, and we are done again.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction: assume $n>3$ and that it is true for $k<n$.

If we have $3|n^2$ then $3$ divides each term of $n^2 - 6n +9 = (n-3)^2$. So we see that  $3| (n-3)^2$ and by the induction hypothesis $3 | (n-3)$ which implies $3 | n$

The statement is vacuously true for $n=1,2$ and obviously true for $n=3$.

Answer (score -1):

Proof by contraposition:

Suppose $ 3 \nmid n$, then $ n \equiv 1 (mod 3)$ or $ n \equiv 2 (mod 3)$

So $n^2 \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 (mod 3) $ or $n^2 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 1 (mod 3) $

Therefore  $ 3 \nmid n^2$

Answer (score -2):

$n^3 + 2n = n(n^2 + 2) = n[(n^2 - 1) + 3] = 3n + {n(n-1)(n+1)} \Rightarrow P + Q$

Here:
$$P = 3n \Rightarrow \text{divisible by } 3$$
$$Q = n(n-1)(n+1) \Rightarrow \text{this is a multiplication of three consecutive number and hence it is divisible by } 3$$
$$\therefore P + Q \text{ is divisible by } 3$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) to format your answer; just using the `*` symbol has another function than you intend.

Comment: What does the divisibility of $n^3+2n$ by $3$ have to do with the question?

Comment: @epimorphic I think the intention is "$n^3 + 2n$ is always divisible by $3$; if $n^2$ is divisible by $3$, then so is $n^3$, and hence $2n = (n^3+2n) - n^3$. Since $3$ is a prime and doesn't divide $2$, it divides $n$". The argument would be more economic using $n^3-n$ and $n = n^3 - (n^3-n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Would be nice if that was carried out fully...