# Prove that if $3\mid n^2 $ then $3\mid n $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

$n \in \mathbb{N}$

Prove that if  $3\mid n^2 $ then $3\mid n $

I want to prove this in a accepted formal way, I thought about the fact that every integer can be written as multiplication of prime numbers. and if we raise this integer to the power two we will get multiples of each prime. $3\mid n^2 $, it means that this $"3"$ must have been in $"n"$ before raising it to the power. I am going to the right direction? and if yes, can someone hint how can I write it formally?

Comment: what's your definition of prime number?

Comment: that can be divided only by itself and $1$. for example: 2,3,5,7,...

Comment: As an alternative way: it is sufficient to prove the contrapositive: $3\not\mid n\implies 3\not\mid n^2$. Which can be done using two cases, one where $n=3k+1$ and the other where $n=3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Every number $n$ has a unique decomposition in primes:
$$
 n = p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \dots p_m^{k_m}
$$
hence 
$$
 n^2 = p_1^{2k_1} p_2^{2k_2} \dots p_m^{2k_m}.
$$
If 3 divides $n^2$ then one of the $p_i$s is equal to $3$ and the corresponding exponent $2k_i$ is different from zero. Hence $k_i$ is different from zero and also $n$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: I was thinking about this. and I can add also that $n$ can't be $1$ in this case because it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

You have the right idea by thinking in terms of unique prime factorization. From Euclid's lemma we know that if $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime and $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Since $3\mid n^2 = n\cdot n$ then 3 must divide $n$.

Of course, if you have never heard of Euclid's lemma before you should try proving it yourself since your proof will provide a nice generalization of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Different approach/hint: Assume that $m^2$ is a multiple of 3, write $m = 3k + a$ with $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \}$ and $a \in \{ 0 , 1 , 2\}$. You have to show that $a \equiv 0$. Square both sides and then use the assumption that $m^2$ is a multiple of $3$, i.e., there exists a $s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ such that $m^2 = 3s$.

Can you finish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the hint : suppose that $3$ does not divide $n$. Then there exists integers $u, v$ such that $nu + 3v = 1$. Now what happens if you multiply both sides by $n$ ?

Comment: yes, but I didn't learn this theory yet, i'm searching for simpler way to understand the proof.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani Well I'm not sure if there is other formal way to prove this. You better check this 'Bezout lemma'.

Comment: @brick "Now what happens if you multiply both sides by $n$?" Correct me if I am wrong, we get $n^2u + 3vn = n $. Now if $3 | n^2$ then $3 | n^2u + 3vn$, which by substitution implies $ 3 | n$ , contradicting our assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $3 \mid n^2$.  We want to show that $3 \mid n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose to the contrary that $3 \nmid n$.

Since $3 \mid n$ means that there exists an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = 3m$, $3 \nmid n$ means that for all $r \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \neq 3r$.

Note that we can square both sides of the inequation

$$n \neq 3r$$

to get

$$n^2 \neq 9r^2$$

for all $r^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The last inequation implies that

$$3^2 = 9 \nmid n^2$$

which further implies that

$$3 \nmid n^2.$$

This contradicts $3 \mid n^2$, and we are done.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. How do you conclude that $9$ does not divide $ n^2$? How do you use this to conclude that $3$ does not divide $ n $?

Comment: $3 \mid n$ if and only if $n = 3a$ *for some* $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, $3 \nmid n$ if and only if $n \neq 3b$ *for all* $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh, my $ n $ at the end should have been an $ n^2$, sorry. My point is that simply because $ n^2$ is not $9r^2$ for any $ r $ you cannot conclude it is not $9t $ for any $ t $. But even that is irrelevant. You have yet to argue that if $9$ does not divide $ n^2$, then $3$ cannot divide it either.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992181/prove-that-if-n2-is-divided-by-3-then-also-n-can-also-be-divided-by-3