# What is wrong with my proof by contradiction that if $n^2$ is divisible by 3, then $n^2$ is divisible by 9?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm working through the book Language, Proof and Logic (2nd ed., Barker-Plummer, Barwise & Etchemendy). This is problem 5.25, presented right after the introduction to proof by contradiction.

Prompt: Assume that $n^2$ is divisible by 3. Prove that $n^2$ is divisible by 9.

Here's my take on it:

1. Assume that $n^2 = 3k \text{ (k being any non-zero integer)}$
2. Let $n^2 \neq 9m \text{ (m being any non-zero integer)}$ (i.e, not divisible by 9)
3. From 2, $n^2 \neq 3(3m)$.
4. From 1, 3, we have $k \neq 3m$. But we have previously said that $k$ can be any non-zero integer. Hence, a contradiction, so $n^2 = 9m \text{ (for a non-zero integer m)}$.

The problem is that, I don't think this is right because I can replace 9 with 81 and do:

1. Assume that $n^2 = 3k \text{ (k being any non-zero integer)}$
2. Let $n^2 \neq 81m \text{ (m being any non-zero integer)}$ (i.e, not divisible by 9)
3. From 2, $n^2 \neq 3(27m)$.
4. From 1, 3, we have $k \neq 27m$. But we have previously said that $k$ can be any non-zero integer. Hence, a contradiction, so $n^2 = 81m \text{ (for a non-zero integer m)}$. Which I can refute giving a counter example n = 3.

I don't think this chapter restrict me to using only proofs by contradiction, but it only allows me to use basic arithmetics and definitions of even / odd (and also prove by cases). I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1746209/381959) should satisfy the requirement by the book.

Yet, I'm curious about what is wrong about my way of proving by contradiction?

Comment: You might try replacing $n^2$ with $6$ everywhere in your argument to understand what's wrong.  (Yes, $6$ isn't a square, but you never used the fact that $n^2$ is a square.)

Comment: This is a high quality question. It includes many details about your thoughts on the problem. Thus I think it deserves more upvotes.

Comment: By the way, if you'd like a proof now the error has been explained, look at the residue classes of $n^2$ modulo $3$ that follow from each option for $n$ to prove by contradiction $3|n^2\implies 3|n$, so you can write $n=3k\implies n^2=9k^2$.

Comment: @Shaun  I agree, we need more of this here. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Assume that $n^2 = 3k$ ($k$ being any non-zero integer)."

There is the problem.  $k$ is *some* integer.  Since $n^2$ is a fixed number, $k$ cannot be anything you want.

The place where you attempt to reach a contraction, "But we have previously said that $k$ can be any non-zero integer" therefore doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. If I understand correctly, would I be able to assert "k is some number, but that number is not multiple of three" at step 4?

Comment: I don't know.  But in order for the proof to work, you have to make use of the fact that $3$ is prime, in some form or other.

Comment: "would I be able to assert "k is some number, but that number is not multiple of three" at step 4" you can (and must) assert that if you are doing a proof by contradiction.  But it might be hard to find the contradiction.

Comment: I think: "[...] but k is not a multiple of 3" --> "But if k isn't a multiple of 3, it can't be a multiple of 9 either" but this doesn't produce a contradiction (it's consistent with contrary of conclusion)... So yeah, I'll solve it another way, but this is interesting nonetheless to tackle it with the hope for contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I think your conclusion 4 is not correct in the first case and the statement 1 should be

**there exists k such that $n^2$=3*k (where k belongs to integer)**

Now coming into the actual proof:-

we have 3 divides $n^2$

implies, 3 divides n (*)

implies 9 divides $n^2$

The statement marked in (*) can be proved trivially by contradiction

Answer (score 0):

You should be saying $k$ is a fixed, nonzero integer (not $k$ is any nonzero integer).

Your proof is incorrect. You didn't get a contradiction.

To do this, I think you need Euclid's lemma:  $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\lor p\mid b$.

Or perhaps the prime factorization.

---

So suppose that $3\mid n^2$.  By Euclid's lemma, $3\mid n$.  So $n=3k$ for some $k$.  Then $n^2=(3k)^2=9k^2$.  Hence $9\mid n^2$.

Comment: I don't think I can touch primes or its property yet at this point. Also, do you mean I can reach a contradiction if I use Euclid's lemma?

Comment: Yes.  Or you could prove it directly.

Comment: You need to use primes.  Substitue $3$ with $4$ (and $9$ with $16$) and it won't be true.  You might manage to avoid the word prime but you will need this property of $3$.  A slightly weaker property than prime can work but it is not true of any integer.

Comment: But Euclid's lemma relies on primes.

Answer (score 0):

you say

1.Assume that $n^2=3k$ ($k$ being any non-zero integer)

Obviously you can't mean $k$ can be *any* non-zero integer.  $k$ can't be ... $5$..., say, because $n^2 = 3*5 = 15$ is simply not possible.

$k$ can be any number so that $3k$ is a perfect square or $k$ can be any $\frac {n^2}3$ so that $\frac {n^2}3$ is an integer but... we really don't at this point of the game have any idea when such numbers are possible and when they are not.

We have to prove that any such $k$ must also be divisible by $3$.

Hint: Consider what happens if $3|n$ or $3 \not \mid n$.  If $3|n$ does $9|n^2$?  If $3 \not \mid n$ does $3|n^2$?